# error 406 Inacceptable Spring MVC 4 Extjs5 JSON response

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson, extjs5

I'am using Spring MVC4  with Exjts5 and I had the **406 Inacceptable** error when sending a `POST` Request to the server.

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Task Management</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tasks/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.example.task.management.controller"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "tasks/edit",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = "application/json",
        headers = "Accept=application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
Result editTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
    return managerService.updateTask(task);
}
```

And here is the javascript code corresponding to the request:

```
 var taskRecord = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'tasks/tasks/edit',
        method: 'POST',
        jsonData: taskRecord.getBean(),
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            console.dir(obj);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
        }
    });
```

pom.xml:

```
 <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.4.4</jackson.version>
    </properties>    
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--Dependency Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the Debuging result

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/tasks/tasks/edit
Request Method:POST
Status Code:406 Inacceptable
**Request Headersview** 
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ar;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:121
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=CEFED652722EA328C45ACCF08CF170B0
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
**Request Payloadview** 
{taskID: 3, taskName: "Implementation", taskDescription: "Implementation", taskPriority: "MEDIUM",…}
taskDescription: "Implementation"
taskID: 3
taskName: "Implementation"
taskPriority: "MEDIUM"
taskStatus: "ACTIVE"
**Response Headers**
Content-Language:fr
Content-Length:1110
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 18 Dec 2014 14:27:25 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Please can youh help me?

Thank you

Comment: what happens if you don't specify `headers` and/or `produces` in @RequestMapping?

Comment: The same result 406 Inacceptable

Comment: What if you use `params` instead of `jsonData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my Problem:

The Object "Result" that my controller method returns had not Getters/Setters for his attributes

Jackson needs Getters/Setters to create the object that will be returned

```
@RestController
public class TaskManagerController {
    TaskManagerService managerService = new TaskManagerService();

    @RequestMapping(value = "tasks/edit",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Result editTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
        return managerService.updateTask(task);
    }
}
```

And the class "Result" is like that:

```
public class Result {

    private String[] messages;
    private String status;
    private Integer code;
    private Object resultObject;

    public Result(String[] messages, String status, Integer code, Object resultObject) {
        this.status = status;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.code = code;
        this.resultObject = resultObject;
    }

    public static Result SUCCESS(String[] messages, Object resultObject) {
        return new Result(messages, "SUCCESS", 200, resultObject);
    }

    public static Result FAILURE(String[] messages, Integer errorCode, Object resultObject) {
        return new Result(messages, "FAILURE", errorCode, resultObject);
    }

    public String[] getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(String[] messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Object getResultObject() {
        return resultObject;
    }

    public void setResultObject(Object resultObject) {
        this.resultObject = resultObject;
    }
}
```